# Blender 2.49 from os import urandom as _urandom ImportError: cannot import name urandom

Tags: python, error

I searched whole 5 pages on google but did not find answer, I have old blender script that I need to run on blender 2.49 but Im getting an error

```
from os import urandom as _urandom
ImportError: cannot import name urandom
```

Blender reqire python 2.6 which I have installed and I have confirmation from blender

```
Compiled with Python version 2.6.2.
Checking for installed Python... got it!
```

I'm not using virtualenv, so it should not be the [issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366821/python-importerror-cannot-import-urandom-since-ubuntu-12-04-upgrade).

I did like [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545030/python-importerror-cannot-import-name-urandom) and added `"print 42"` to end of `/usr/lib/python2.6/os.py` and I'm getting printed 42 when I run blender and that os.py does not end with definition of urandom, precisely

Does anyone has any suggestion tnx

Comment: Can you import it when running python in the shell?  Recall  blender 2.49 used python 2.7

Comment: No I cant import it in shell. No python 2.49 comes in two verisons python 2.5 and python 2.6